# executeUpdate(String sql) Method in Statement Class with a insert query which has ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm executing an insert query in my net beans java application.

```
public boolean Update(){
    String sql="insert into customer(cNic,cName,cAddress,cTp,cEmail,creditLimit,CustomerStatus)"
            + "values('"+cs.getcNic()+"','"+cs.getcName()+"','"+cs.getcAddress()+"','"+cs.getcTp()+"'"
            + ",'"+cs.getcEmail()+"','"+cs.getCreditLimit()+"',0) "
          + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cName=VALUES(cName), cAddress=VALUES(cAddress), "
            + "cTp=VALUES(cTp), cEmail=VALUES(cEmail), \n" +
                "creditLimit=VALUES(creditLimit),CustomerStatus=0;";
    try {
        Statement stmt=dbConn.createStatement();
        int rslt =stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(rslt==1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "DB_CONNECTION ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }

}
```

This method works well for new rows. 
But when I add a row (which has a primary key already in the table)  the `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)` method returns 2. But the data has been updated in the table. But I can't check whether the insertion has been done successfully. In normal cases if the execution is success it returns 1. Is there a way to execute this query in net beans and to know whether it has been updated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing please do me a favour  replace the Statement with PreparedStatement

[executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())- returns the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements

`method returns 2` means two rows got affected

`But I can't check whether the insertion has been done successfully`

if it was not inserted it would have returned either 0 or thrown an exception

Answer (score 0):

Thats right you dont need to save your stmt.executeUpdate() function as an int.
If the update succeeds it will work and you can return true (Assuming you want it to return true, if it works), otherwise and this is the case if an exception will be thrown, your code leads to the catch clause and therefore will return false;

I would suggest you to rewrite your method I'll give you an example with  a piece of my code :

```
public boolean update(Long id) throws SQLException{
        Statement stmt = dbCon.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
       String allRoomsToArchive = String.format("Update Room SET "
                + "archive=1 WHERE building_id=%s;",id);
        stmt.executeUpdate(allRoomsToArchive);

// You always need to close your statements and connections, as for security reasons, and // also because sometimes, you will have too many connections, so that your query can not // be done. A connection does not automatically close after your statement has finished!

stmt.close();
dbCon.close();


}
```

The advantage of this way is that you can call your update-method from another methode e.g. callUpdate() and handle the Exception in there. 
If you have to do many sql-queries you can put them in a queue, and need to handle it only once with a try catch like in here, but also if its your only one it looks smoother that way:

```
public boolean callUpdate(){


try{
 update();
 // update2();
 // update3();

 return true;
}catch(SQLException e){
 System.out.println(e.toString());
 return false;
}

}
```